# Java FXML: Why is my imageView not Showing, and how can I upload an image from my computer?

Tags: java, image, javafx, uiimageview, fxml

I'm doing a project where I need to upload an image and apply some filter to it. For that I am using javaFx FXML. It is the first time I am using this tool, so I am a bit(lot) lost. I created a simple interface using fxml controler and I added some buttons and also an imageView field. In the image view fiel I also added a default image that appears normally while I am in applying it, but it wont show the image when I actually run the project, all I see is a blank space where the picture was supposed to be. Does someone know why it happens?
Plus as you guys are going to see in the code, I would like to know how I can have access to the imageView src so I can upload an image and change it at anytime using JFileChooser. Thank you very much.

```
Controler

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package fotofinish;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    private JPanel      jpanel, jpanelbar;
     JLabel              image;
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button filterGrayscaleButton;
    @FXML
    private Button filterSepiaButton;
    @FXML
    private Button filterInstantButton;
    @FXML
    private Button filterCustomButton;
    @FXML
    private Button filterNoneButton;
    @FXML
    private Slider brightnessSlider;
    @FXML
    private Slider contrastSlider;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup brushTypeRadioGroup;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeCircleRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeSpraypaintRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeSquareRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarHelpFotoFinishHelpMenuItem;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarHelpAboutMenuItem;
    @FXML
    private Label filtersLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label sliderLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label brightnessLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label contrastLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label drawingLabel;
    @FXML
    private ColorPicker brushColorPicker;
    @FXML
    private Label brushTypeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label brushSizeLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField brushSizeTextField;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileNew;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileOpen;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileGalleryButterfly;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileGalleryTeddyBear;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileGalleryPrincess;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileGalleryFirefighter;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileSave;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileSaveAs;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem menubarFileQuit;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //TODO: make call function only when value changes by certain threshold
        brightnessSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println("TODO: brightness changed to " + newValue);
            }
        });

        contrastSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println("TODO: contrast changed to " + newValue);
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void applyFilterGrayscale(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: grayscale filter applied");
    }

    @FXML
    private void applyFilterSepia(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: sepia filter applied");
    }

    @FXML
    private void applyFilterInstant(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: instant filter applied");
    }

    @FXML
    private void createFilterCustomPopup(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: launched custom filter popup");
    }

    @FXML
    private void applyFilterNone(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: none filter applied");
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeBrushTypeCircle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: brush type changed to circle");
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeBrushTypeSquare(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: brush type changed to square");
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeBrushTypeSpraypaint(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: brush type changed to spraypaint");
    }

    @FXML
    private void displayHelpDoc(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: launched help document");
    }

    @FXML
    private void displayAboutDialog(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: created about dialog");
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeBrushColor(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: brush color changed to <BRUSH COLOR>");
    }

    @FXML
    private void adjustBrushSize(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: brush size changed to <BRUSH SIZE>");
    }

    @FXML
    private void openFile(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: launched file picker");
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.print(f.getAbsolutePath());
        //image = new JLabel("", new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath()), JLabel.CENTER);
        //jpanel.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //jpanel.revalidate(); //ADD THIS AS WELL
        //jpanel.repaint();
    }

    @FXML
    private void openFileGalleryButterfly(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: opened butterfly file from gallery");
    }

    @FXML
    private void openFileGalleryTeddyBear(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: opened teddy bear file from gallery");
    }

    @FXML
    private void openFileGalleryPrincess(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: opened princess file from gallery");
    }

    @FXML
    private void openFileGalleryFirefighter(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: opened firefighter file from gallery");
    }

    @FXML
    private void saveFile(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: saved file");
    }


    @FXML
    private void saveFileAs(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: launched file save as dialog");
    }


    @FXML
    private void quit(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(1);
        System.out.println("TODO: quit program");
    }

    @FXML
    private void createNewFile(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TODO: created new file");
    }
}
```

FXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fotofinish.FXMLDocumentController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileNew" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createNewFile" text="New">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="N" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileOpen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFile" text="Open">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="O" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open from Gallery">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryButterfly" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileGalleryButterfly" text="Butterfly" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryTeddyBear" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileGalleryTeddyBear" text="Teddy Bear" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryPrincess" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileGalleryPrincess" text="Princess" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryFirefighter" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileGalleryFirefighter" text="Firefighter" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileSave" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveFile" text="Save">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileSaveAs" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveFileAs" text="Save As">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileQuit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit" text="Quit">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="C" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator></MenuItem>
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="menubarHelpFotoFinishHelpMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#displayHelpDoc" text="Foto Finish Help">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="F1" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator></MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarHelpAboutMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#displayAboutDialog" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.14941569282136896" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="filtersLabel" text="Filters" />
                        <Button fx:id="filterGrayscaleButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#applyFilterGrayscale" text="Grayscale" />
                        <Button fx:id="filterSepiaButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#applyFilterSepia" text="Sepia" />
                        <Button fx:id="filterInstantButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#applyFilterInstant" text="Instant" />
                        <Button fx:id="filterCustomButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createFilterCustomPopup" text="Custom" />
                        <Button fx:id="filterNoneButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#applyFilterNone" text="None" />
                        <Label fx:id="sliderLabel" text="Sliders" />
                        <GridPane prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="175.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="88.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="23.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="290.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="287.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="brightnessLabel" text="Brightness" />
                              <Label fx:id="contrastLabel" text="Contrast" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                              <Slider fx:id="brightnessSlider" min="-100.0" minorTickCount="5" orientation="VERTICAL" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Slider fx:id="contrastSlider" min="-100.0" minorTickCount="5" orientation="VERTICAL" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                        <Label fx:id="drawingLabel" text="Drawing" />
                        <ColorPicker fx:id="brushColorPicker" onAction="#changeBrushColor" />
                        <Label fx:id="brushTypeLabel" text="Brush Type" />
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeCircleRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeBrushTypeCircle" selected="true" text="Circle">
                           <toggleGroup>
                              <ToggleGroup fx:id="brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                           </toggleGroup>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeSquareRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeBrushTypeSquare" text="Square" toggleGroup="$brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeSpraypaintRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeBrushTypeSpraypaint" text="Spraypaint" toggleGroup="$brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                        <Label fx:id="brushSizeLabel" text="Brush Size" />
                        <TextField fx:id="brushSizeTextField" onAction="#adjustBrushSize" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="369.0" prefWidth="465.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="AnchorPaneScrollPaneImageView" fitHeight="479.0" fitWidth="585.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../Pictures/images.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a reference in your Java controller to the [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) you defined in FXML.  You do this using the [`@FXML` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation).

Currently you have this:

```
<ImageView fx:id="AnchorPaneScrollPaneImageView" ...
```

That will work, but is kind of a long name and does not follow the Java/FXML naming convention of starting ids of instance variables with a lower case (it's also wrong because you don't have a ScrollPane), so just change it to:

```
<ImageView fx:id="imageView" ...
```

Then insert a reference to it in your code (as you have for all of the other FXML defined elements):

```
@FXML
private ImageView imageView;
```

To select an image you can write:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Open Image File");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
     new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"),
);
File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainStage);
```

And when you want to set the image to it, you can do:

```
if (selectedFile != null) {
    imageView.setImage(selectedFile.toURI().toURL());
}
```

Note: I haven't tested the above code snippets.

*Aside*

Mixing Swing and JavaFX is inadvisable unless you really need it and is not advised at all if you are just learning FXML. Delete java.awt and javax.swing imports and their usages from your code and replace the functionality with their JavaFX counterparts. For example, JavaFX includes a [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html), so you should use that rather than a [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).